# Problema com execução de funções

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu tenho um codigo de um GUI em python usando tkinter, com opções que abrem em uma janela outros modulos que fiz. Tenho também um botão abre uma musica que importei com playsound.

```
root.sound = Button(root.frame_baixo, text='Som', bg='#28282b', font=('Helvetica', 11, 'bold'), fg='#ffffff', cursor='hand2',command=lambda: playsound('media/jam.mp3'))
```

Ao apertar o botão a musica toca, mas não consigo escolher as opções para abrir os modulos, o programa simplesmente para de responder, ou seja... Não consigo executar as duas ações ao mesmo tempo, alguem pode me ajudar a como fazer isso funcionar?

Exemplo de opção que chama outro modulo e abre um video mp4

```
root.radio_valor = IntVar() # Cria os radio buttons e o label e os empacota
root.label = Label(root.frame_cima,text='Bem-vindo ao BASKETBOT, o Preditor de arremessos no Basquete! Selecione uma opção:', bg='#000',fg='#fff', font=80)
root.cesta1 = Radiobutton(root.frame_cima, text='1: Cesta', bg='#000', fg='#fff', pady=10, padx=10, font=40,variable=root.radio_valor, value=1, command=lambda: main.main1())
```

Botões

```
root.quit = Button(root.frame_baixo, text='Sair', bg='#28282b', font=('Helvetica', 11, 'bold'), fg='#ffffff', cursor='hand2',command=root.quit) # Cria os botões e empacota
root.sound = Button(root.frame_baixo, text='Som', bg='#28282b', font=('Helvetica', 11, 'bold'), fg='#ffffff', cursor='hand2',command=lambda: playsound('media/jam.mp3'))
root.quit.pack(side='left', ipadx=40, ipady=10, expand=True)
root.sound.pack(side='right', ipadx=40, ipady=10)
```

Ou aperto em um ou em outro, mas queria que o som executasse ao fundo do programa, como não consegui de outra forma tentei por botão, mas assim a opção não abre ao clicar.
Exemplo de opção que chama outro modulo e abre um video mp4

```
root.quit = Button(root.frame_baixo, text='Sair', bg='#28282b', font=('Helvetica', 11, 'bold'), fg='#ffffff', cursor='hand2',command=root.quit) # Cria os botões e empacota
root.sound = Button(root.frame_baixo, text='Som', bg='#28282b', font=('Helvetica', 11, 'bold'), fg='#ffffff', cursor='hand2',command=lambda: playsound('media/jam.mp3'))
root.quit.pack(side='left', ipadx=40, ipady=10, expand=True)
root.sound.pack(side='right', ipadx=40, ipady=10)
```

Ou aperto em um ou em outro, mas queria que o som executasse ao fundo do programa, como não consegui de outra forma tentei por botão, mas assim a opção não abre ao clicar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute `playsound` em uma [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), pois a causa da sua aplicação parar de responder é porque ao chamar a função `playsound('media/jam.mp3')` ela é executada na Main Thread da sua aplicação,
veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread
from playsound import playsound

def play():
    playsound("media/jam.mp3")

window = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(master=window, width=150, height=150)
frame.pack()

button = tk.Button(frame, text='Som', bg='#28282b', font=('Helvetica', 11, 'bold'), fg='#ffffff', cursor='hand2',command=lambda: [Thread(target=play, daemon=True).start()])
button.place(x=20, y=50)

button2 = tk.Button(frame, text='Sair', bg='#28282b', font=('Helvetica', 11, 'bold'), fg='#ffffff', cursor='hand2',command=window.quit)
button2.place(x=80, y=50)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Show amigo, deu certo. Mas ai o botão de sair que tinha o root.quit parou de funcionar mesmo eu colocando da mesma forma que você disse acima

Comment: Adicione o parâmetro `daemon=True` na Thread, e veja se root.quit funciona. Fiz alteração na resposta verifique.

Comment: Deu certo amigo, coloquei o daemon=True e agora os botões e as opções que chamam os modulos funcionam, só uma coisa, me explica o motivo do daemon=True? Gostaria de entender o motivo e não só usar o códoigo.

Comment: Veja essa pergunta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/190010/12112704) ela explica sobre daemon(daemonic) em Threads.